# Story identification: Everyone turns into a fantasy creature

Tags: books, story-identification

I read a book in a library around 2000AD that I have been trying to remember since.

A town of people is suddenly (or not so suddenly) transformed into creatures, monsters, or people of a fantasy nature. At least one townsfolk turned into a bear.

Of the main characters there was one male who turned into a "hero", a female who 
turned into a nymph/dryad and another female who turned into a griffin.

The main characters originally thought they had escaped the random transformations until over time they changed as well, with the griffin girl quite upset about it until someone told her that a griffin was a symbol of honor and pride or something to that effect.

The cause of the transformations was a mystery and the main characters were I believe trying to discover it.

Comment: The "everyone in town turns into a fantasy character" trope has been used many times. To help identify this particular one, start by telling us when you were young, then add some other details,

Comment: Edited with as much detail as I can remember, will continue to do so if I recall something more.

Comment: I like the clarification that you read it around 2000AD, not BC :-P

Comment: @Blair Or *BBY*

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd I’ve now spent 10 minutes trying to come up with jokes combining wookies and gryphons for which you are entirely to blame

Comment: @Blair I'll take it